# differences in ink coverage results: ghostscript inkcov vs tiffsep method (vs APfill)

Tags: python, ghostscript

Looking for a way to get the ink coverage from a pdf file to make quotes for printing jobs, I've come across a discrepancy I can't get my head around.
There is a difference in ink coverage result comparing three methods.

Searching the web we've come across APFill (trial version) which does the job: the test file gives following result:

[image: ApFill Result]

I was looking into a getting the same result with open source methods. Since APFill uses Ghostscript, I used the inkcov device for the following result:

```
gs -o - -sDEVICE=inkcov testfile.pdf
```

which gave the following result:

```
Page 1
 1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  0.76546 CMYK OK
```

Which is clearly not the same result as the ApFill one. The Ghostscript result also seems wrong considering the test file is not a almost complete 'rich black' filled out document.

So I researched a bit further and used the Ghostscript tiffsep device to split the pdf in tif files per color seperation

```
gs -o test.tif -sDEVICE=tiffsep -r300x300 testfile.pdf
```

which I used to count percentage pixel values using numpy and opencv in python:

```
img = cv2.imread('test(Cyan).tif', 0)
inkcovIMG = img/np.full(img.shape, 255)
print (1-np.mean(inkcovIMG))
img = cv2.imread('test(Magenta).tif', 0)
inkcovIMG = img/np.full(img.shape, 255)
print (1-np.mean(inkcovIMG))
img = cv2.imread('test(Yellow).tif', 0)
inkcovIMG = img/np.full(img.shape, 255)
print (1-np.mean(inkcovIMG))
img = cv2.imread('test(Black).tif', 0)
inkcovIMG = img/np.full(img.shape, 255)
print (1-np.mean(inkcovIMG))
```

This gave following results:

```
0.5188357078732435
0.4992922045543696
0.5949687851445294
0.5271387924864341
```

which are more or less the same as the APFill result.

So my question here would be: does GhostScript inkcov device just counts the amount of pixels where a color is used, instead of also considering the amount of color used in a seperate pixel? Or am I overseeing something?

Thanks for any comments!

Comment: It woudl be useful to know which version of Ghostscript you are using in each case, and to see the input PDF file. I'm suspicious of the answer you have got from inkcov, 100% CMY seems unlikely. Using tiffsep could give a different answer, because it renders in an odd way if there are spot colours in the PDF file. I can't comment on APFill because I don't know anything about it.

Comment: I'm using Ghostscript 9.26. There are no spot colours in the PDF. It contains a full bleed image with a sepia like tint. You can download it here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/15999878f038aa27411bc82422b1d47020190415110103/03898b67363a737f9f8dc1884e1ebf0220190415110103/dd07fd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is you are using the wrong device :-) Somewhat surprisingly, there are two ink coverage devices which calculate the coverage in different ways. You are using the inkcov device, try using the ink_cov device instead.

For me that gives the result:

```
GPL Ghostscript GIT PRERELEASE 9.28 (2019-04-04)
Copyright (C) 2019 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
51.86353 49.92667 59.47390 52.62051 CMYK OK
```

Which is exceedingly close to your tiff32 result. Changing the resolution will give subtly different results due to the way the image samples are laid down on device pixels.

The device source code is in ghostpdl/devices/gdevicov.c the 'inkcov' device has a comment saying :

```
 * columns 1 through 4 give the fraction of pixels containing
 * c, m, y and black ink.
```

The ink_cov device comment says:

```
/*  cov_write_page2 gave ink coverage values not ratecoverage */
```

So one is the percentage of pixels containing a (CMYK) colourant, the other is the percentage of ink over the entire page.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. Perfect answer to my question and includes a solution!  Since you had to look into the sourcefiles, I'm not feeling that guilty ;). Maybe this difference should be added to http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.27/Devices.htm#Test .

Comment: Well, I probably didn't have to go to the sources, but running a debugger is my default option for figuring out Ghostscript things. When I saw there were two devices the problem became obvious :-)

Comment: What's the difference between "ink coverage" and "ratecoverage" referring to ink_cov device comment? I have a red square in a test PDF-file, consisting of 100% Magenta and 100% Yellow, but `gswin64c -o - -sDEVICE=ink_cov "A4RED.pdf"` gives also black as a result `0.00000  0.34796  0.34796  0.93776 CMYK OK` -how can that be?

Comment: I haven't seen the PDF content so I can't comment. I don't remember what the difference is (and if you look at the comments you'll see it is a contributed device). Bear in mind also that there are two ink coverage devices with confusingly similar names; inkcov and ink_cov. one gives you ink coverage the other gives you rate coverage as I recalll.